# AWS Metrics shows there is data in Bucket but S3 bucket is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, no-data

I logged on as a admin and I am owner of the bucket I have all permission ( List,Write )
When I check with metrics I see data in bucket , I see same thing in Cloudwatch but when I access it
i can not see any objects in the bucket.

I can create new folder. I can access it but there is no data in the bucket.

I wonder any of you had same problem?

I would like to access the data in the bucket if there is any

Comment: You may have versioning on the bucket. So there may be older versions of the files that was in bucket.

Comment: Use `aws s3api list-object-versions` to see if there are any deleted versions of objects and `aws s3api list-multipart-uploads` to see if there are any abandoned multipart uploads.